# How can I join two MySql Database tables using Django and fetch data from both of them and view in browser using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Actully I wrote a code in python using Django and MySql Database to join two tables and fetch data from both the tables and view them in browser using Django Rest Framework...I want to use raw sql query to do so and I have done so but it is not working...I am posting the code. Can anyone please help me out...???And yes I am using  pagination...and data is coming from one table only...Please help....

view.py

```
 @api_view(['GET','POST'])

 def index(request):

  if request.method=='GET':

     all_dataobj=fetchdata.objects.raw("SELECT fetchdata.*, 
     fetchdata_dum.* 
     FROM fetchdata LEFT JOIN fetchdata_dum ON fetchdata.id = 
     fetchdata_dum.fetchdata_id")

     paginator = CustomPagination()
     result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(all_dataobj, request)

     pserializer=fetchdataSerializers(result_page,many=True)

     return paginator.get_paginated_response(pserializer.data) 

     # return Response(pserializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

  elif request.method=='POST':

   serializer=fetchdataSerializers(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():

        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models

class fetchdata(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  email = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  ma_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  menu_item_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  item_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  meta_key = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  meta_value = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  date_added = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  date_updated = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
      db_table = 'fetchdata'

class fetchdata_dum(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField
  fetchdata_id = models.IntegerField
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  email = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  ma_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  menu_item_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  item_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  meta_key = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  meta_value = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  date_added = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  date_updated = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
       db_table = 'fetchdata_dum'
```

Comment: someone please help me out with this one????

Comment: what is the error you are getting?